# Calculate the cumulative values grouping by 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df called df_normales:

```
          CODE         MONTH     NORMAL_PP
    0     000261      January      111.4
    1     000253      January      46.5
    2     000375      January      86.5
    3     000229      January     203.6
    4     152204      January      52.6
         ...        ...       ...
    6403  000858     December      0.5
    6404  000861     December      60
    6405  000179     December      5.7
    6406  000458     December     240.1
    6407  002412     December     236.7

[6408 rows x 3 columns]
```

I want to calculate the accumulated values of 8 months by code. In other words, for each code I would like to have the accumulated data from January to August, February to September, March to October, and so on for all (including September to April) of the NORMAL_PP column.

Expected Result:

```
  DATE_START  NORMAL_PP DATE_END    CODE
0   12            79.5    07       000009
1   01            76.2    08       000009
2   02            50.9    09       000009
3   03            25.7    10       000009
4   04            4.2     11       000009
..      ...        ...      ...       ...
```

Values of DATE_START and DATE_END are the months (12 = December, 01 = January, etc).

So i tried this code:

```
oct_norm=pd.DataFrame()
for code, datost in df_normales.groupby('CODE'):
    new_row = {'DATE': '2019-12-01', 'NORMAL_PP': datost.loc[datost['DATE'] == '2020-12-01', 'NORMAL_PP'].item()}
    datost = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(new_row, index=[0]), datost]).reset_index(drop=True)
    
    out_normales=(datost.groupby(pd.to_datetime(datost['DATE']).dt.to_period('M'))['NORMAL_PP'].sum()
        [::-1].rolling(8).sum()[::-1]
        .reset_index()
        .assign(DATE_END=lambda d: d['FECHA'].add(7))
       )
    out_normales['CODIGO']=code
    oct_norm=oct_norm.append(out_normales)
```

The issue is that i'm not getting some of the 8 month consecutive values. This is what i'm getting (sample of a specific CODE value):

```
      DATE    NORMAL_PP DATE_END  CODE
0   2019-12       79.5  2020-07  000009
1   2020-01       76.2  2020-08  000009
2   2020-02       50.9  2020-09  000009
3   2020-03       25.7  2020-10  000009
4   2020-04        4.2  2020-11  000009
5   2020-05        4.7  2020-12  000009
6   2020-06        NaN  2021-01  000009
7   2020-07        NaN  2021-02  000009
8   2020-08        NaN  2021-03  000009
9   2020-09        NaN  2021-04  000009
10  2020-10        NaN  2021-05  000009
11  2020-11        NaN  2021-06  000009
12  2020-12        NaN  2021-07  000009
```

Comment: Do you only have data between 2019-12 and 2020-12?
Within the rolling member function if you add the argument min_periods = 1 this should solve the problem.